# Count from a dataframe, then sort based on that count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm attempting to group a dataframe by products, get a count of each product, and then sort so the most frequent product is at the top of the resulting series.

Currently my code looks like:

```
    def return_most_products(self, df):
        most_products_series = df.groupby('Product')['Product'].count()
        most_products_series.sort_values()
        return most_products_list
```

Which works to sort the series by the 'Product' column alphabetically. As the count column doesn't have a header that I can see I'm stumped as how to indicate that I want to index, and sort, based on the count rather than the product.

Comment: df['Product].value_counts() will give you what you want. is the expected different to this output?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!